# Incorrect frame when dismissing modally presented view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller, uipresentationcontroller

I am presenting a `UIViewController` using a custom transition and a custom `UIPresentationController`. The view controller's view does not cover the entire screen, so the presenting view controller is still visible.

Next, I present an instance of `UIImagePickerController` on top of this view controller. The problem is that when I dismiss the image picker, the presenting view controller's frame covers the entire screen instead of just the portion I want it to cover. The frame specified by `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` in my custom `UIPresentationController` seems to be completely ignored.

Only if present the image picker with a `modalPresentationStyle` of `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` my frames remain intact (which makes sense since no views are removed from the view hierarchy in the first place). Unfortunately that's not what I want. I want the image picker to be presented full screen, which - for whatever reason - seems to mess up my layout. Anything that I might be doing wrong or forgetting here? Any suggestions?

Comment: have similar problem but with `UIActivityViewController` and only when using full-screen sharing, such as Messages or Mail

Comment: For me, the incorrect full screen frame when dismissing modally presented view controller appears momentarily before the correct view appears.

Answer (score 18):

I tried both wrapper approaches mentioned. One side effect of using this wrapping approach is that device rotation doesn't display well - introducing black boxes around the presented view.

Instead of doing the wrapping trick, try setting the `modalPresentationStyle` of the presented `UIImagePickerController` to `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`. This means the views underneath the image picker won't be removed/restored from the view hierarchy during presentation/dismissal.

Comment: This is much better -- much less of a hack, and more guaranteed to work long-term

Comment: Holy cow.... I was banging my head on every hard surface trying to figure this out. Never could've imagined this to be such a simple solution. Thanks so much ! :) BTW, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This seriously saved my butt. Had an issue with this only related to the iPhone X. Thanks man!

Comment: This absolutely works when you have control over the controller you're presenting, like UIImagePickerViewController. But when you present a UIActivityViewController and then the user selects something like "Save to Files" or "Messages", the UIActivityViewController is dismissed and then something else gets presented (e.g. the Messages composer), and in that situation you aren't given a callback to set the modalPresentationStyle. So the same bug occurs when the user is finished with saving to files or sending a message. Any thoughts on applying this approach in that situation?

Comment: on dismissing modally presented view controller with this approach, the presentedviewcontroller of UIPresentationController now remains fullscreen :(

Answer (score 4):

This is expected because the fullscreen presentation does not restore the original frame computed by `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView`.
The recommended way to fix this is to create a wrapper view in which you will insert the presented view controller's view. Here is the relevant code for your custom presentation controller:

```
- (void)presentationTransitionWillBegin {
    // wrapper is a property defined in the custom presentation controller.
    self.wrapper = [UIView new];
    [self.wrapper addSubview:self.presentedViewController.view];
}

- (CGRect)frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView {
    CGRect result = self.containerView.frame;

    // In this example we are doing a half-modal presentation
    CGFloat height = result.size.height/2;
    result.origin.y = height;
    result.size.height = height;

    return result;
}

- (UIView *)presentedView {
    return self.wrapper;
}

- (BOOL)shouldPresentInFullscreen {
    return NO;
}

- (void)containerViewWillLayoutSubviews {
    self.wrapper.frame = self.containerView.frame;
    self.presentedViewController.view.frame = [self frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView];
}
```

Note that we override `presentedView` to return the wrapper view instead of the default value – the presented view controller's view. This way, even if the second presentation modifies the wrapper's frame the presented view controller's view will not change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @erudel but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. What I get from this is that the custom presented view controller is correct **after** the dismissal animation of the view controller it presented which is an effect that I had already achieved previously by simply re-adjusting the frame of the presented view controller's view in `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews` (no need for the wrapper view). **During** the dismissal animation, however, the view's frame remains full screen, which results in a jumpy layout change and is of course incorrect in the first place.

Comment: `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews` handles bound changes such as rotation or adaptation, but the wrapper view is needed exactly for avoiding that "jump" when dismissing the fullscreen presentation.

Comment: The thing is that I implemented it exactly the way you proposed but I still get the jump @erudel.

Comment: Can you share your code? I wrote a sample test app with the code above and it behaves correctly.

Comment: Work for me! Nice!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, in `UIPresentationController`:

```
override func containerViewWillLayoutSubviews() {

     super.containerViewWillLayoutSubviews()
     presentedViewController.view.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[erudel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37982262/5529003) didn't work for me as is, but adding another view in between `wrapperView` and `presentedViewController.view` did the trick (I have no idea why):

```
- (instancetype)initWithPresentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presentedViewController
                       presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presentingViewController {
    if (self = [super initWithPresentedViewController:presentedViewController
                             presentingViewController:presentingViewController]) {
        _wrapperView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        _wrapperView2 = [[UIView alloc] init]; // <- new view
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGRect)frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView {
    return self.containerView.bounds;
}

- (UIView *)presentedView {
    return self.wrapperView;
}

- (BOOL)shouldPresentInFullscreen {
    return NO;
}

- (void)containerViewWillLayoutSubviews {
    self.wrapperView.frame = self.containerView.frame;
    self.wrapperView2.frame = /* your custom frame goes here */;
    self.presentedViewController.view.frame = self.wrapperView2.bounds;
}

- (void)presentationTransitionWillBegin {
    [self.wrapperView addSubview:self.wrapperView2];
    [self.wrapperView2 addSubview:self.presentedViewController.view];

    // Set up a dimming view, etc
}
```

Tested this on iOS 9.3.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews` but it wasn't quite working. I wanted to avoid the extra wrapper views if possible. I came up with this strategy of correcting the frame on the view using the `presentedView`. In addition I was able to remove `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews`. `forceFrame` is tuned to our particular use case. `presentedFrame` is set by our custom animator.

```
class CustomModalPresentationController: UIPresentationController {

        var presentedFrame = CGRect.zero
        var forceFrame = false

        override func dismissalTransitionWillBegin() {
            forceFrame = false
        }
        override func presentationTransitionDidEnd(_ completed: Bool) {
            forceFrame = true
        }
        override var presentedView: UIView? {
            if forceFrame {
                presentedViewController.view.frame = presentedFrame
            }
            return presentedViewController.view
        }
        override var frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView: CGRect {
            return presentedFrame
        }
    }
```

Comment: This one fixed it for me. For reasons I can't be bothered to go into, changing the `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` would have been nice but was actually beyond my control without a larger refactor (external library usage). Wrappers seemed clunky. This fixed it nicely for me though! Thanks!